# Snackbar in Android is not displayed

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I use a single-activity multiple-fragments approach in my app and I would like into display a snackbar (instead of displaying a toast, which I did without any problems).

Here is the code of the Fragment in which I would like the snackbar to be displayed after pressing a button:

```
package com.example.td.bapp;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.example.td.bapp.databinding.FragmentItemBinding;
import com.example.td.bapp.R;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;



public class FR_Item extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Nullable

    private FragmentItemBinding binding;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        
        /*
        Set onClickListeners to the buttoms
         */

        binding.orderingButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.ordering_button) {

            showSnackBar(getActivity(), getString(R.string.message_orderSubmittedSuccessfully));

        }


    }


    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    public void showSnackBar(Activity activity, String message){
        /*
        1st try
         */
        View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Log.e("LogTag", "showSnackbar - Try 1");
        Snackbar.make(rootView, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       
         /*
        2nd try
         */
        
        Log.e("LogTag", "showSnackbar - Try 2");
        Snackbar.make(activity.findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I tried in two ways that are recommended here: `[Snack bar not displayed][1]`. In both cases the `showSnackBar` method is being calles (I can verify that becasue of the LogTag) but no text is displayed in the app. `R.id.mainActivityLayout` is the id of the ConstraintLayout of my main activity (in the 2nd try) and `android.R.id.content` I have no clue what this is (in the 1st try). I just took this from the accepted Stackoverflow answer. I also tried to replace it with this (in the 1st try) `View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.mainActivityLayout);`

In all 3 cases the result is the same. There is no SnackBar visible and there is no error message (not even in the autmatically created LogCat error messages). Do you have any idea, what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try `binding.getRoot()` instead of `rootView`?

Comment: @hata: Thanks for your comment hata. I just tried your suggested code but there is no change at all. The snackbar is not displayed (altough the method is executed) and there is no error message.

Comment: can you add snippet of error code ? because is is strange I just use you code snippet of showSnackBar function it perfectly working fine.

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya: Thanks for your comment. As stated in the question, there is no error code and no information in any logcat about this issue. Still, the Snackbar is not displayed.

Comment: In my single-activity multiple-fragments approach I use a BottomNavigationBar in the singel activity (that is displayed then in very fragment). Might it be possible that this BottmNavigationBar is somehow overlaying the SnackBar?

Comment: Okay to debug this issue in your project i would suggest you to  first try to toast sanckbar for temparory inside you single main activity and see if it is works there or not then can move to next checks.

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya: Thanks for your comment. I just put the code inside my main activity and there it was working fine.

Comment: Okay Great !! as work around for now you can invoke this function from fragment as if it works fine for you

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya: Thanks for your comment. I can't invoke this method from a fragment but just from the main activity (I put the code inside the onCreate method). This is useless for me and does not help at all. I have to invoke this method from different fragments. And this does not work at all

Comment: I mean to say is use it as function same as you created above. and from fragment when ever you want to display snackbar just invoke this function using. (getActivity() (MainActivity)).showSnackBar()

Comment: @MaulikTogadiya: Thanks for your comment. I get errors when applying your suggested code ". (getActivity() (MainActivity)).showSnackBar()". Are you sure that there are no syntax errors in it? Where exactly shall I call this code? I called it in the Fragment (after pressing the button).

Comment: Strangely it seems to work now (altough in the Fragment) even tough I did not change anything. I think the problem might have been caused by the Emulator, which is extremely slow on my laptop. But thanks to all your comments. I really appreciate it.